# Read Doc file and file path from Browser

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I have an issue that I want to read a **DOC** file in my system but the condition is

Suppose you are working on browser and download some **PDF** or **DOC** file ,then my program should run and get the path of that file and convert that doc file in binary format.

the file download path may be change because some time it download in default folder but some times you saves that file in other locations.

my concern is this that code should execute at download time and should get file path from download history and read that file.

Comment: So where are you struggling?? I can only see a scenario here

Comment: @huMptyduMpty I have no idea how to get the download details so that i can findout the file location where it was downloaded